# threshold signature scheme that allows adding and removing members

Tags: dsa, schnorr-signature, threshold-cryptography

Is there a threshold signature scheme (TSS) that a quorum in a group can sign, where members can dynamically join and leave, without changing the shared group public key? ECDSA, BLS, and Schnorr based TSS are preferred, since the desired use case is in blockchain.

Comment: Leaving (that is, revoking someone's share) sounds tricky; if we had $t=3$ (three can sign), and we have Larry, Moe and Curly as valid members (so the three of them can sign without interacting with anyone else), and then we revoke all three, how do we make sure that Larry, Moe and Curly can't get together after revocation and jointly sign anyways?  We can't force them to forget anything, and they originally did have the knowledge how to generate valid signatures...

Comment: Leaving on its own is generally possible, and can be achieved by so-called resharing protocols that essentially reshare the existing shared secret without modifying it. In the threshold setting. We are guaranteed that enough parties can reconstruct the secret keys. And that shares before the refresh are basically inconsistent with new shares. Which effectively nullify that knowledge, assuming enough people deleted their shares after a successful reshare. See https://ia.cr/2021/060 for a good refresh protocol.